# Silicon Image storage controller

Tags: controller

I am unable to update the BIOS for Silicon Image storage controller. How do I install and/or upgrade the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

Please refer to the How-to Update BIOS Technical Tip  for an explanation of how to update BIOS for Silicon Image storage controllers. This technical tip includes a list of FLASH memory chips supported by the BIOS update utilities. BIOS can be updated with the BIOS file downloads and BIOS update utilities on the Silicon Image support site ONLY for add-in card controllers that have SUPPORTED FLASH memory chips. Controllers embedded in motherboards have their BIOS integrated into the system BIOS of the motherboard requiring that you get BIOS updates from the motherboard manufacturer. For add-in cards with FLASH memory chips that the Silicon Image utilities will not support, BIOS update tools are often available from the card manufacture or included on the driver distribution CD-ROM that came with the card.